# Android How to change the title for each activity using actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I want to know that how can i use the different title for each activity using ActionBarSherlock. Like Setting's Activity should label Settings on the title bar etc

```
public class Main extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener, OnItemLongClickListener
```

Answer (score 5):

in each activity you can call programmatically

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle(title);
```

it takes as parameter both an int or a charsequence. Lile setText of a TextView

Answer (score 1):

You mean how to set the title in the Actionbar? In that case it is:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.yourString);
....
```

Comment: He's talking about Actionbar Sherlock, not the native one

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can do this by:

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
    android:label="@string/settings">
</activity>
```

And to do this for each of your activities, which are defined in the `AndroidManifest`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to set tile..

```
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setTitle("My Title");
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use it in your manifest where you declare

```
   <activity android name ".pckgname"
            android : label = "activity name"   
            >
 </actrivity>
```

and    remove this method from your activity

```
       this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```